Webtoon where the main character is a young king who is the only king without a god
The webtoon/manga where the young king is frail and they are in some sort of fantasy setting. Each state has its own thing and for each king there is a corresponding god, he doesn't have a god and they go to a meeting for each state it's pretty old around 2010 or so I cannot remember the name.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Full color it was a webtoon or a manwha

This is Divine Bells.

Divine Bells - they choose their own masters and they determine the status, prestige, and influence of the countries their masters rule. The presence or lack of these Bells also has great consequence in the lives of each country's royalty. In particular, the personal and political futures of King Hong-Ryeong seem doomed without a Bell, but at equally great peril if he obtains one.But are the Divine Bells simple magical charms, deities of great powers, or something else altogether? And when the owner of three of the eight existing Divine Bells dies, leaving them to choose new owners, where will the resulting turmoil lead?

The protagonist is the king of a small nation, and the only one that does not possess one of the divine bells, and has never possessed one.

The bells are the gods mentioned in the question. This appears to be unknown to the characters in the story, but the prologue chapter shows humans (presumably gods) turning into the bells. The protagonist at least considers them to be purely symbolic, only capable of choosing an owner and nothing else.
The meeting takes place in chapter 2; one of the kings dies and his three bells will choose new owners from among the gathered royalty. It is mentioned that the bells of the deceased have always stayed within the family, but at this gathering the bellless king gets one of the bells.

OMG bless you yes this is

@Momo You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as accepted, which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the tour.
